# displaying text with apostrophe

Tags: php, apostrophe

I have this code

```
echo "<img src='".MY_URL."/uploads/avatars/blank.gif' class='img-circle' title='$name' border='0' alt='".$name."' height='48' width='48'>";
```

How do i display this properly if $name is Abbas Sa'ad

It always echo `Abbas Sa` only

Comment: use double quotes as your html attribute delimiters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) with `ENT_QUOTES` like below:-

```
echo "<img src='".MY_URL."/uploads/avatars/blank.gif' class='img-circle' title='". htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) ."' border='0' alt='". htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) ."' height='48' width='48'>";
```

Comment: @blackrx  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
str_replace("'","\'",$name);
```

Comment: Thanks i used the solution provided by @Alive To Die